# How to plot in a graphical interface using MatplotLib the values received from a sensor?

Tags: python, matplotlib, interface, arduino, archive

I am developing a graphical interface that asks you the name of the new file to be generated of type txt and that asks you the serial port on which your Arduino is located, when you start the python program connects to Arduino with the specific port and receives 25 sensor data (use a potentiometer to perform the tests) and this received data is written to the text file , in addition to this to show in the graphical interface the results would put them on a graph. The problems I have encountered in fulfilling my goal are as follows

Reads the data as bytes so when you save it to the text file it stores it this way

```
b'NUMBER\r\n'
```

and this means that when you want to use replace('b\r\n','') give me a

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

This in turn means that when you graph the data is not put in ascending order but by appearance

[image: Values received from the graphed sensor]

At the moment I do not know how to capture this graph that is generated in the interface when it ends but if I do not solve this first will not do any good.

I leave the part where I try to replace commented so that they know where I put it, here my python code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tkinter import*
import serial, time
def createTEXT(reading):
    text=''
    for i in range(len(reading)):
        text += str(reading[i]) + ' '

    return text

def graph(reading):
    y=[]
    for i in range(len(reading)):
        y.append(reading[i])
    return y

def SEND():
    NAME=str(NOMBRE.get())
    PORT=str(PUERTO.get())
    PORT=str(PUERTO.get())
    try:
        arduino = serial.Serial(PORT,9600)
        time.sleep(4)#Stabilize the connection
        for i in range(25):
            arduino.write(b'1')#Bits are sent here
        reading=[]
        
        for i in range(25):
            reading.append(arduino.readline())
        arduino.close()
        
        # for i in range(len(reading)):
        #     reading[i][len(reading[i])-1] = reading[i][len(reading[i])-1].replace('b\r\n','')
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Please verify that the Port you put in is the right one", title="ERROR")

    archive = open(NAME+".txt","w") #Open the file in write mode "write" 
    Text=createTEXT(reading)

    archive.write(Text)
    archive.close()
    print(Text)
    y=graph(reading)
    plt.plot(y)

    # plt.show

POTENTIOMETER = Tk()
frame = Frame(POTENTIOMETER)

#Objects to use
ASKNAME = Label(frame,text= "Welcome, what name will this new file have?")
NOMBRE = Entry(frame)
ASKPORT = Label(frame,text= "Which port your ARDUINO UNO is connected to?")
PUERTO = Entry(frame)
SEND= Button(frame, text = "SEND", command = SEND)


#Content
ASKNAME.pack()
NOMBRE.pack()
ASKPORT.pack()
PUERTO.pack()
SEND.pack()
frame.pack(padx = 200, pady=150)#Tamaño márco
POTENTIOMETER.mainloop()
```

And here's my Arduino code, the one I'm using is Arduino One and so it's all connected
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
int s = 0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);

}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.read() == '1') {
    delay(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
      s = analogRead(A2);
      delay(500);
      Serial.println(s);

    }
  }
}
```

as you may have seen I put a `print(text)` to view from the python console without opening the file.txt what was saved, here I leave you what is printed

```
b'1016\r\n' b'1019\r\n' b'1016\r\n' b'1018\r\n' b'1016\r\n' b'1017\r\n' b'1019\r\n' b'1018\r\n' b'1016\r\n' b'1018\r\n' b'1018\r\n' b'965\r\n' b'1016\r\n' b'1002\r\n' b'1018\r\n' b'781\r\n' b'1019\r\n' b'1018\r\n' b'1019\r\n' b'1019\r\n' b'1019\r\n' b'1019\r\n' b'811\r\n' b'418\r\n' b'369\r\n'
```

the program is made so that the graph is similarly displayed in the python console until the program is closed